# Is one string located inside the other?

Tags: c, string, function

User give us longer string `s` and a shorter one `t`.

If `t` is in `s`, where the symbol `?` in string `t` can be used as any character, display a message.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int isit(char*,char*,int);
int main()
{
    char s[20],t[20];
    int k,i,fir;
    puts("Enter first string");
    gets(s);
    puts("Enter second string");
    gets(t);

    k=strlen(s)-strlen(t);

    for(i=0;i<=k;i++){
        fir=i;
        if(isit(s,t,fir)==1){
            printf("It's in there");
            return 1;
        }
    }

}
int isit(char*s,char*t,int fir){
    int i;
    for(i=fir;i<i+strlen(t)-1;i++)
        if(t[i]!=s[i] && t[i]!='?')
            return -1;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: do not use `gets()`, its deprecated. Use `fgets()` instead. BTW, whats the question?

Comment: if s='straga' and t='aga', then t is located in s, and it should display the confirmation

Comment: or if t='a?a' then it's also located in t

Comment: @Desperado  What problem do you get ?

Comment: adding to @Haris ' comment: **never ever use `gets()`**! It's not only deprecated, it's deprecated for a *strong* reason -- it will eventually overflow *any* buffer and therefore is a security risk.

Comment: using the examples from comments i get (using code blocks) process returned 4, without printf message

Comment: 3. comment edit, "in s"

Comment: `i<i+strlen(t)-1` is the condition to stop the loop...My guess is that you wanted to use `i<strlen(t)`

Comment: You can use the strstr() function to find the one string is placed in another string.

Comment: @sureshkumar that was exactly my first thought, but read the question: it won't fit the bill because there's a placeholder defined for *any character*.

Comment: this line: `for(i=fir;i<i+strlen(t)-1;i++)` is comparing signed and unsigned values.   (read the man page for strlen())  you will notice strlen() returns a `size_t`, not an `int` and `size_t` is an unsigned type

Comment: for readability, only one variable declaration per statement and only one statement per line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the function `isit()`

---

1) When you are checking for the string, in `isit()`. The index for `t` and `s` has to be different. For `s` it has to start from `fir` but for `t` it has to start from `0`.

2) you dont need to do `-1` in the termination condition check, because you are already using `<`, and not `<=`

3) you need to change the termination condition to `i<fir+strlen(t)`, because `i` is changing at every iteration, and that invalidates the termination condition

---

Change the code to

```
int isit(char*s,char*t,int fir){
    int i, j;
    for(i=fir, j=0; i<fir+strlen(t); i++, j++)
        if(t[j]!=s[i] && t[j]!='?')
            return -1;
    return 1;
    }
```

Comment: @ameyCU, Np, which college are you from, i see youre from India.

Comment: fixed and added printf("it's not located") after FOR in main(), and it gives me "it's not located".

Comment: I cannot convince myself that the stopping condition is `i<i+strlen(t)`. What happens if `t` is identical to `s` ? This stopping condition will not be activated and there will be an attemp to read pass the end of the array `t`, with potential undefined behavior...Would not `i<fir+strlen(t)` be better ?

Comment: @francis, i just tested and made the same changes before reading your comment. :)

Comment: @Desperado, tested and edited, its working now. Go through the changes.

Comment: @ameyCU, nice to see you here everyday answering. :)

Comment: please stop chit-chatting in comments (no offense, it's just not helpful) ... use the chat feature instead :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen, yup, just wanted to know few things. :)

Answer (score 4):

Among other problems, function `isit` does not use the correct index for `t`.  It would be much simpler written with pointers and should return boolean values `0` or `1`:

```
int isit(const char *s, const char *t, int first) {
    for (s += first; *t; s++, t++) {
        if (!*s || (*s != *t && *t != '?'))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Also use more consistent spacing and more explicit variable names: 1 letter local variable names are OK if the function is short and the name is idiomatic (`i` for an index, `s` for a `char *`...), but silly abbreviations are not (`fir` for `first`).  Function name `isit` bears no information as to what it does!  As a matter of fact, you do not even need a function, you could use a standard function for this:

```
strncmp(s + first, t, strlen(t)) == 0
```

EDIT: but as M.Oehm noted, this would not handle the `?` wildcards.

Comment: `strncmp` won't treat the `?` wildcard as desired, of course. Otherwise, sound advice.